# Error using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 storyBoards. The first one - a tableViewController called "st1" has static cells with 5 labels, and 5 textFields and 2 buttons. The next storyBoard - a viewController called "st2" has a tableView.

When I segue from st1 to st2, it gives me the error below.

I am using size class and auto layout.

```
2015-01-18 13:10:40.199 myApp[1108:35975] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 

(

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa1f1d2a310 V:[UITextField:0x7fa1f1d283c0(30)]>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa1f1d30780 UITextField:0x7fa1f1d283c0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa1f1d271a0.topMargin>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa1f1d30870 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa1f1d271a0.bottomMargin == UITextField:0x7fa1f1d283c0.bottom - 3>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa1f1d64d00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa1f1d271a0(43.5)]>"

)



Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 



Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

It displays this error 5 times. I just cut it out so it would be easier to read.

I'm a beginner as you can probably tell, so please don't be too harsh on me.

Comment: When I delete all textViews, it doesn't give me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is complaining because you have constrained the text field height to 30 (that is the '(30)' in the first constraint), but you also want the top of the text field at the top margin of its cell and the bottom at the bottom margin of the cell -3 and the height of the cell is 43.5.  So you are simultaneously asking for the text field to have a height of 30 and 40.5 - which is a conflict.

Either constrain the top & bottom of the text field and don't set the height

*or*

Set the height and don't set a bottom constraint

*or*

Adjust the height of the cell (probably not the best solution)